# FileNet 4.0 P8 Jboss 4 - Cannot login - Credentials Exception

Tags: java, jboss, filenet-p8

I am using Filent 4.0 and Jboss 4, it was working well but recently I got the Credentials Exception error message when trying to login to Workplace.

```
Error Message:
Credentials Exception

Exception Class:
com.filenet.wcm.toolkit.util.WcmException

Stack Trace:
Credentials Exception 
at com.filenet.wcm.toolkit.server.base.WcmSignInPolicy.encodeTokenException (WcmSignInPolicy.java:345) 
at com.filenet.wcm.toolkit.server.base.WcmSignInPolicy.getSignInURL (WcmSignInPolicy.java:332) 
at com.filenet.wcm.toolkit.server.base.WcmSignInPolicy.doSignIn (WcmSignInPolicy.java:301) 
...
```

I already tried to stop/start JBoss Server, Application Engine server (P8) and purge the cache as following 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21967918
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_4.5.1/com.ibm.p8.install.doc/p8pup363.htm

But it does not work. I am out of solutions, any ideas ? Anyone does know FileNet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We reboot the server, and finally the error did not show anymore, maybe all services were not reinitialized at the last restart.